# Thorntail MP JWT / Undertow: required authentication

Tags: security, jwt, undertow, jaspic, thorntail

I'm trying to set up a JAX-RS-service in thorntail with JWT authentication. Everything works fine (I can inject `Principal` and user is correctly set), except that in case of a failed authentication, answer is still sent without any 401-HTTP-Header. What I've done is:

- Added `@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT", realmName = "my-domain")` to my `Application`-Class
- Configured the security-domain

  ```
  security:
    security-domains:
      my-domain:
        jaspi-authentication:
          login-module-stacks:
            roles-token-stack:
              login-modules:
                jwt-jaspi-login-module:
                code: org.wildfly.swarm.microprofile.jwtauth.deployment.auth.jaas.JWTLoginModule
                flag: required
        auth-modules:
          http:
            code: org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jaspi.modules.HTTPSchemeServerAuthModule
            module: org.wildfly.extension.undertow
            flag: required
            login-module-stack-ref: roles-token-stack
  ```
- Configured JWT-specific things (seem to work, so I'm skipping this here)

What else do I need to do in order for this to work properly? Do I need to add any annotations to my Endpoint? As I said, I want to return a 401 in case of a failed authentication.

What I've found out so far: `JASPICAuthenticationMechanism.isMandatory` needs to return true in order for this to work. If this is the case `JWTAuthMechanism.sendChallenge` is triggered after a failure of `JWTAuthMechanism.authenticate` and so a 401 is sent to the client. But i have no idea, in which cases `isMandatory` returns true.

Thanks for any help in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (thanks to Ladicek, see comments below):

If you want to use MP JWT, don't start it with `Swarm` and don't forget to set flag `useUberJar` if starting it with `thorntail:run`.

Answer (score 1):

One, the configuration of the security domain isn't 100% correct. Here's a fix for one part of the YAML:

```
      roles-token-stack:
        login-modules:
        - login-module: jwt-jaspi-login-module
          code: org.wildfly.swarm.microprofile.jwtauth.deployment.auth.jaas.JWTLoginModule
          flag: required
```

Two, indeed you need to use the common Java EE annotations (`@RolesAllowed`, `@DenyAll`, `@PermitAll`) on the JAX-RS resources.

Comment: I changed the configuration of the security domain and added a `@DenyAll` to the endpoint...but still no luck in getting a 401 on failed authentication. `JWTLoginModule` is called (has been called with the old config too), i check it by setting a breakpoint in `login()`. This method throws a LoginException, which in my opinion should lead to a 401?

Comment: At this point, I don't see anything obviously wrong. Do you have a minimal but complete reproducer somewhere? Also feel free to look at a couple of MP JWT tests here: https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/microprofile/microprofile-jwt-1.0

Comment: I tried the test-suite and it works fine if running with arquillian. But if I run it with `org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm` in my IDE and then try to access `http://localhost:8080/denied` the return code is 200 instead of 401. I'm unable to try it with Maven and `thorntail:run` because i always get _[INFO] Starting uberjar
Error: Unable to access jarfile_  and I don't know how to fix this. What is the difference between running it with arquillian an running it standalone?

Comment: Running the `Swarm` class in an IDE is very buggy (basically because it doesn't run an uberjar, but tries to reconstruct the same classloading environment from classpath, which doesn't really work). You can try the `Runner` as described in https://thorntail.io/posts/thorntail-runner/ As for `mvn thorntail:run`, that doesn't work in the testsuite because the `thorntail-maven-plugin` isn't configured, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to get the Runner to work, but this seems to be a litlle bit difficult. Every time I start it, it will take a whole lot of time (>1h!) till an error message is thrown. And because i have to configure a specific repository and I'm behind a proxy I will probably need a few tries... :-)

Comment: `Runner` works now. And I see the correct behaviour, 401 if something goes wrong. The same with `thorntail:run`. If I try `Runner` in my project, correct behaviour too. But if I try `thorntail:run` on my project, i get a 200. Very strange. I will investigate this a little further next week.

Comment: Ha, I know what might be going on with `mvn thorntail:run`. I think that by default, it also uses the classpath mode. Can you try `mvn thorntail:run -Dthorntail.useUberJar`?

Comment: That was it! What a long journey for such a small flag. Thank you for your help. So, in conclusion, if you want to use MP JWT, don't start it with `Swarm` and don't forget to set flag `useUberJar` if starting it with `thorntail:run`.